# accessing previous element in fold/reduce in dart

Tags: dart, collections, reduce

I wonder if I can rewrite this piece of dart code:

```
 double length = 0;
 Point current = points.first;
 for (var next in points.skip(1)){
   length += current.distanceTo(next);
   current = next;
 }
 return length;
```

to something more concise and elegant. I was thinking about using reduce / fold, but is there a way to access precedent element of iterable in combining function?

Comment: This points are cordinates? right?

Comment: Yes, in this specific case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With functional programming style and dart extension methods:

```dart
extension MyExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T foldByPairs(T initialValue, T combine(T value, T previous, T current)) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = this.iterator;
    iterator.moveNext(); // error handling omitted for brevity
    T value = initialValue;
    T previous = iterator.current;
    while (iterator.moveNext()) {
      T current = iterator.current;
      value = combine(value, previous, current);
      previous = current;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is always an alternative of for loop with iterable.
Implemented a **logic of Fibonacci** here and checked the performance.

```
import 'dart:math';

double fibSum = 0;
double quesSum = 0;
List<Point> listOfPoints = [Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(1, 4)];

void main() {
  print("before fibonacciLogic: ${DateTime.now()}");
  fibonacciLogic(listOfPoints.length);
  print("after fibonacciLogic: ${DateTime.now()}");

  print("before logicFromQuestion(): ${DateTime.now()}");
  logicFromQuestion();
  print("after logicFromQuestion(): ${DateTime.now()}");

  print("output fibonacciLogic: $fibSum");
  print("output logicFromQuestion: $quesSum");
}

fibonacciLogic(int length) {
  if (length < 2) {
    return length;
  }
  fibSum += listOfPoints
      .elementAt(length - 2)
      .distanceTo(listOfPoints.elementAt(length - 1));
  return fibonacciLogic(length - 2) + fibonacciLogic(length - 1);
}

logicFromQuestion() {
  Point current = listOfPoints.first;
  for (var next in listOfPoints.skip(1)) {
    quesSum += current.distanceTo(next);
    current = next;
  }
  return quesSum;
}
```

**output:**

```
before fibonacciLogic: 2020-04-22 14:39:37.170
after fibonacciLogic: 2020-04-22 14:39:37.172
before logicFromQuestion(): 2020-04-22 14:39:37.172
after logicFromQuestion(): 2020-04-22 14:39:37.173
output fibonacciLogic: 4.414213562373095
output logicFromQuestion: 4.414213562373095
```

**Outcome:**
Here logic provided in question with for loop is taking 2 microseconds while Fibonacci Logic takes only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an answer I found - using additional objct (it seems to be also slightly faster) :

```
class Point {
  int x;
  Point(this.x);
  int distanceTo(Point p) {
    return p == null ? 0 : (x - p.x).abs();
  }
}
class PointAccumulator {
  Point current;
  int length = 0;
  PointAccumulator(this.current);
}
void main() {
  List<Point> points = [Point(1), Point(10), Point(20)];
  int loops = 1000000;
  int length = 0;
  Stopwatch s = Stopwatch();
  s.start();
  for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {

    // Standard method
    length = 0;
    Point current = points.first;
    for (var next in points.skip(1)) {
      length += current.distanceTo(next);
      current = next;
    }


  }
  s.stop();
  print(s.elapsed);
  print(length);
  PointAccumulator pa;
  s = Stopwatch();
  s.start();
  for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {

    // with extra object
    pa = points.fold(PointAccumulator(points.first),
        (PointAccumulator pa, Point next) {
      pa.length += next.distanceTo(pa.current);
      pa.current = next;
      return pa;
    });



  }
  s.stop();
  print(s.elapsed);
  print(pa.length);
}
```